# Can I deploy pods in public and private subnets?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-vpc

I am currently trying to identify the required AWS VPC and Subnet structure for EKS.

However, would like to check whether I can deploy the UI containers (pods) and the Spring Boot based API Gateway pods in public subnet and deploy all other back-end service pods in private subnet.

Is it possible to create such Kubernetes YAML deployment configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You deploy the UI containers (pods) and the Spring Boot based API Gateway pods in `nodes that run in public subnet`, all other back-end service pods in `nodes that run in private subnet`. Where nodes are really just EC2 instance that runs kubelet that have joined your EKS cluster. Typically, you use `nodeSelector` or `affinity` to direct which node for your pod to run.

Comment: Thanks @gohm'c !! So while adding nodes in the EKS Cluster I need to select the specific subnet. Please correct me here.

Comment: You do not need to do that by hand, EKS uses ASG to managed EC2 that will join the cluster; the ASG is where you specify the subnet.